# Why can't I call 'public void' from the same class?

Tags: c#, methods

My understanding of the method structures is limited to a very limited spectrum of structures:

```
public / private
static
void / variable returns
string, int etc.
```

So why can't I call a method within the same class?

```
class ClassName
{
    public void Method1()
    {
        // do stuff...
    }

    public static void Method2()
    {
        // This won't work?
        Method1();

        // do stuff...
    }
}
```

Comment: You can't called a non-`static` method from a `static` context because there simply might not be an instance of that class to call the non-`static` method upon. `static` methods don't require an instance to be created prior to calling it.

Comment: Side note: you can get an article describing most common cases for each particular error if you click on error message in Visual Studio and press F1.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't call a non-static method from a static method.
If you really want to do that from withing a static method, you need to instantiate the class, something like:

```
    class myClass
    {
        public void Method1(){
          //Stuffs
        }

        public static void Method2(){
         myClass c=new myClass();
        c.Method1();
        }
     }
```

Comment: So what will instantiating the class this way do?

Comment: As others pointed, a non-static method *requires* the class to be instantiated (as example because it could require some class attribute to be initialized that will be assigned in the costructor), so even if you have to just execute an operation on-the-fly, you need to instantiate the class. If you need to call a method without instantiating it, and you don't need to refer to any attribute of the class, make that method static aswell.

Answer (score 1):

You can't call a method that isn't static from a static method..

Static = belongs to the class

Otherwise it belongs the **instance** of the class.

See MSDN reference for more information about [static methods](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/98f28cdx.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

You can't call a non static element from a static context. You would have to create an instance of your class in your static method and call the non static method from that instance. A static method can be called without an instance.